# How to resolve connection issues from MySQL Workbench client to AWS RDS server?

Tags: mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I want to connect MySQL Workbench to the newly created AWS-RDS database instance, but it always throws this error when trying to initiate a connection from Workbench.

[This is the error message window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IZ7V.png)

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause is that your RDS Security group does not have a rule including your IP.

[image]